# Disable bootstrap for small resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I'd like to create mobile version of my app without using bootstrap (which is used in desktop version)
Simplify, I don't want to download bootstrap stylesheets on resolution smaller than 768px.

Is it possible?

Comment: dont want to download or dosent want to apply styles?

Comment: Something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)?

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and from the settings disable the part of Bootstrap you don't want to use!

Another solution could be to use just the code of the bootstrap.css file you want, editing it manually! For example delete all the part where it says @media.... this will delete all the styling modifications for smaller screens plus you will make your bootstrap.css file smaller which will speed up your page load time!

Hope this solution helps!

Answer (score 0):

First:
if you are loading bootstrap css inside the `<head>` of your document, you should remove it. That will help your browser to load your page faster... instead of stop the rendering process to make an HTTP call to REQUEST bootstrap and then wait to download the Bootstrap CSS from your server or a CDN to finish parsing your DOM.

Instead you should load your css at the end of your file and just ask to load it just if your screen size is smaller than 768px :)

I hope this help...

```
<script>
(function(){
    var screenSize = window.innerWidth;
    if(screenSize>768) {
        var bootstrapStyles = document.createElement('link');
        bootstrapStyles.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
        bootstrapStyles.href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
        document.head.appendChild(bootstrapStyles);
    }
})();
</script>
```